# Change of argument of $\exp(z)-z$ on each side of a square

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, roots

Show that as the positive integer $N$ tends to $\infty$, the change in argument of $e^z − z$ is bounded on $3$ sides of the square with corners $ \pm 2\pi N$ $\pm 2\pi iN$ but is unbounded on the fourth side.

Show that $e^z = z$ has infinitely many complex roots.

Comment: What's the contribution of the two exclamation marks to the title?

Comment: Maybe it's a double-factorial argument of some kind.

Comment: (joking, of course)

Comment: looks like homework question

Comment: What have you tried? Which of the sides do you think will give the large change in argument?

Comment: I used 1/2\pi i \int e^z-1/e^z-z dz , but I can not show the bounded

Comment: I took this integral over the line z=2\pi N +iy where -2\pi N<y< 2\pi N and I substitute this for z and dz=idy

Comment: then for the bound |\int ..| < \int |dz| |e^{2\pi N +iy}|+1 / (|e^{2\pi N +iy}|+|2\pi N +iy|)  but I do not know what I how to show that it is bounded!

Comment: Please Please help me :) @mrf

Answer (score 1):

- On either horizontal side, $\arg z$ changes by $\pi/2$ while $\arg e^z$ is constant due to $e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}$.
- On the left side,  $\operatorname{Re}(e^z-z) \ge -|e^z|+2\pi N=e^{-2\pi N}+2\pi N>0$.
- On the right side, $e^z$ traverses the circle of radius $e^{2\pi N}$ exactly $2N$ times, and the term $z$, having the modest modulus $|z|\le N\sqrt{2}$, can't do much about that.

The conclusion about roots follows from the argument principle.